# Share OpenGraphStory with ShareApi.share FacebookSDK, android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Im trying to share an opengraph object from my android app. Here is my code:

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "SDK inicijalizirano");
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                    Log.d("Success", accessToken.getToken());
                    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                            .putString("og:type", "books.book")
                            .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
                            .putString("og:description", "In the frozen S")
                            .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
                            .build();
                    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                            .setActionType("books.reads")
                            .putObject("book", object)
                            .putBoolean("fb:explicitly_shared", true)
                            .build();
                    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                            .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
                            .setAction(action)
                            .build();
                    ShareLinkContent linkcontent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
                            .build();

                    ShareApi.share( content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Story posted! " + result);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "canceled");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "error posting: " + e.getMessage());

                        }
                    });


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Canceled");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Not OK");
                    if (exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_in);
    shareOnFacebookBox=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.share_on_facebook_checkbox);

    shareOnFacebookBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(shareOnFacebookBox.isChecked()){
                Log.d(TAG, "chekirano");
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null){
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                }
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(ActivityCheckIn.this, PERMISSIONS);

            }else{
                System.out.println("Un-Checked");
            }
        }
    });
```

When i try ShareApi.share(linkcontent, new FacebookCallback...); it works.
When i try ShareApi.share(content, new Face.....) it comes with

```
    09-07 10:11:04.940  22452-22452/? D/Success﹕ CAAPP8XKZCZCzEBADo2jAMmrZBsKhn9zOYaC4VZAYtbXttjgazmSal8yxPOUOHgJioiMfT5ZCkBeDWzWBJluX6LSXaRW8jBnsPtrD3tfYcKa1rrlHSubPO4si0riMCORl0okCpLxlRehLOXKMJWZBCOHLqt4YbfjuZCoRRDh595B2ZCFYMuzWs6CpJhcknSDCnK1451ixtAYIyWeOP6mjn00WEpZCobuviZAvNadI6JEOjZCRwZDZD09-07 10:11:05.600  22452-22452/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.teamwe.go/com.teamwe.go.activities.ActivityCheckIn}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3660)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:792)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:819)
        at com.facebook.internal.CollectionMapper.iterate(CollectionMapper.java:60)
        at com.facebook.share.ShareApi.stageCollectionValues(ShareApi.java:456)
        at com.facebook.share.ShareApi.stageOpenGraphAction(ShareApi.java:484)
        at com.facebook.share.ShareApi.shareOpenGraphContent(ShareApi.java:221)
        at com.facebook.share.ShareApi.share(ShareApi.java:165)
        at com.facebook.share.ShareApi.share(ShareApi.java:73)
        at com.teamwe.go.activities.ActivityCheckIn$1.onSuccess(ActivityCheckIn.java:141)
        at com.teamwe.go.activities.ActivityCheckIn$1.onSuccess(ActivityCheckIn.java:117)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:509)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:192)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:140)
        at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
        at com.teamwe.go.activities.ActivityCheckIn.onActivityResult(ActivityCheckIn.java:349)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3656)
```

and here is my

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);}
```

**Note that: Im successfully Login in, it prints the accessToken in log, than the app crash.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend you try this with our latest SDK and with the RPSSample & Scrumptious bundled samples. You would get an idea on how to handle `onActivityResult()` ... etc